# Visual Studio variable declaration

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project that has the following line in the additional includes section:

"$(SOMEPATH_SHORTNAME)\include"

Can someone tell me where I can find $(SOMEPATH) defined? I can't find it by simply searching in Visual Studio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's not an environment variable, the place to look is the macros.  In the property sheets, click the (...) button beside the "Addition Include Directories" line, and expand the "Macros>>" button in the dialog that pops up.

Answer (score 2):

Check your environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
- Click the Advanced tab.
- Click Environment variables.
- Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:
- Click New to add a new variable name and value.
- Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name or value.